# How to activate an event once no keyboard or mouse input is detected

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cookies, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create a batch file that will run from a scheduled task. In this batch file I want it to look if the mouse has moved at all or if there are keyboard inputs. If there are neither of these after x amount of minutes then it will close the browser that's open, clear the cookies and relaunch the browser. This is all an auto log-out mechanism for a kiosk so users don't leave themselves logged in.
Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
$p1 = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
Start-Sleep Seconds 1
$p2 = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position
if($p1.X -eq $p2.X -and $p1.Y -eq $p2.Y) {
goto run
} else {
do nothing
}

:run
Taskkill /im firefox.exe

CD C:\Users\jaydons\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\tm4m0rax.default
del *"cookies.sqlite"*

CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox
start firefox.exe http://sysaid.sdairy.com/Login.jsp

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate("Mozilla Firefox")
WshShell.SendKeys "{ALT}", "{TAB}"
```

The part of closing the browser and clearing cookies etc, was working but now it's acting up and will create the new tab then close everything. Also the code for finding the mouse movement isn't working correctly. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, also if anyone could tell me how to incorporate keyboard input into this code that would be very appreciated!

If any of this is confusing please ask what part needs clarification.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you have written for detecting mouse position is written in PowerShell, and won't run in a batch-file. Is PowerShell an option for you to use instead of batch?

Comment: FWIW, you can remove the need to clear the cookies by launching Firefox in private browsing mode.  `start /wait "" firefox -private-window "http://sysaid.sdairy.com/Login.jsp"`.  By the way, the `start /wait` thing might solve your "create the new tab then close everything" problem.

Comment: Set your batch file to only run when idle in Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Noodles, has a great answer.  You can then use the conditions tab to set how long you want the idle time.

Comment: @Toomaja Yes I can use powershell instead, batch-files just seemed simpler. How do I create a powershell script?

Comment: @rojo When launching it in private browsing what would I do then to auto log them out? Just refresh the page?

Comment: @Jaydon kill and relaunch Firefox.